# Meta tag is not showing in page view source, that added using jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, seo

I am adding Meta Tag using jQuery. meta tag is showing in the firebug but not showing when I see in Page View source.

```
    $('head').append('<meta name="description" content="XXXXXX">');
```

How to add meta tag using javascript or JQuery, that I can see in the page view source??

Will Spider crawl through that dynamic contents? For SEO

Comment: Ya sure, source of page is source of page, not showing dynamic change

Comment: +1: I think it's a legitimate question

Comment: Concerning Spider crawl, no they don't. Set it server side then.

Comment: -1 since it's *not* a legitimate question but total lack of knowledge and will to research. Source is source, dynamic content is dynamic content. Dynamic content is **NOT** written to a flat file (in this case source). Therefore, JS added **dynamic** content is not available in the source. Not researching before asking this question is a no-no. Please use google next time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thumb Rule: Any dom manipulation done using JavaScript will not be visible in the view source.

Comment: Also anything done in the front end won't be picked up by search either, so it is best to add it in the php of your site!